# knockout.mapping drop down list, get selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am having an issue understanding how i'm supposed to get the selectedValue of a select (drop down) list i've binded using knockout.mapping.

heres the ajax call and mapping:

```
 var EmailCollection;
 function GetAllEmailsAjax() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:54756/api/Email",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",

                success: function (data) {
                    GetAllEmails(data);
                }
            });            
        }
        function GetAllEmails(data) {
            // not sure if this is 100% correct but it does seem to work as expected
            if (!EmailCollection) {
                EmailCollection = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            }
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, EmailCollection);
            ko.applyBindings(EmailCollection);
        }
<select data-bind="options: EmailCollection, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

as i understand it i need to specify the value in the select data-bind attribute. So it would be something like this:

however, this would mean that selectedEmail would need to be a part of my model. However as all this is being created by knockout.mapping im unsure how i do that.  I am presuming some kind of Model like the following but I am unsure on how to go about it.

```
var EmailViewModel = {
   selectedEmail : ko.Observable(),
   Emails : EmailCollection // the previous model mapped bound in a scenario like this
};
// EmailViewModel.selectedEmail() would then contain my selected value..
```

I'm sure once i see it on paper it will all become obvious just at the moment im struggling to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one email will be selected (implied since you're using a dropdown), you should create a variable to hold the selected email id.  If it defaults to the first email in the collection, you'd do something like this:

```
var selectedEmailId: ko.observable();
...
function GetAllEmails(data) {
...
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, EmailCollection);
selectedEmailId(EmailCollection.peek().Id); //Assuming EmailCollection is an array
ko.applyBindings(EmailCollection);
}

<select data-bind="options: EmailCollection, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: selectedEmailId"></select>
```

selectedEmailId should then be updated any time the dropdown selection is changed.

Comment: Close, remove the `optionsValue: 'Id'` from the `<select>` element and this will do what you're expecting.  Otherwise, `selectedEmail` will be the selected email's id value. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjyAT/)

Comment: Edited answer to reflect @Dennis 's comment (thanks, btw).  If you want the variable to be the entire email variable, go with what he said; if you just want the id, go with what I said.

Comment: And then you could: `var selectedEmail = ko.computed(function(){ return ko.utils.arrayFirst(EmailCollection(), function(email){return email.Id() === selectedEmailId()}); });`  Now you have the best of both worlds!  Although I'd probably go with the selectedEmail and no optionsValue since there's no performance difference and you have access to the entire email object rather than just the Id.  And you can still have the selectedEmailID with just: `var selectedEmailId = ko.computed(function(){ return selectedEmail() ? selectedEmail().Id() : null });` but now we're getting into preference-land.